# Place Annotations on Map with NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

Thanks for the help in advance... this one has been killing me for the past couple of hours.

I am currently pulling in a JSON feed and storing it in a NSDictionary & NSArray. I'm trying to add an annotation for each item being pulled in (time, type, latitude, and longitude). So far, I can extract each value from the Array and have them all repeat with a "for" in the console (see code below).

How to I store these values as an annotation? Any help would be great.

Below is my failed attempt...

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

 // Download JSON Feed
 NSDictionary *feed = [self downloadFeed];
 NSArray *streams = (NSArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"stream"];


 [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
 [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
 [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
 MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
 region.center.latitude = 29.719023;
 region.center.longitude = -114.157110;
 region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
 region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
 [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

 [mapView setDelegate:self];

 int Info;
 for (Info = 0; Info < streams.count; Info++) {
  NSDictionary *stream = (NSDictionary *)[streams objectAtIndex:Info];
  NSLog(@"Time: %@", [stream valueForKey:@"TheTime"]); 
  NSLog(@"Type: %@", [stream valueForKey:@"Type"]); 
  NSLog(@"Longitude: %@", [stream valueForKey:@"Longitude"]); 
  NSLog(@"Latitude: %@", [stream valueForKey:@"Latitude"]); 

  NSString *getLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", [stream valueForKey:@"Latitude"]];
  NSString *getLong = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", [stream valueForKey:@"Longitude"]];

  NSString *getCoord = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"{%@,%@}", getLat, getLong];
  getCoordinates = getCoord;


  DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
  ann.title = @"%@", [stream valueForKey:@"TheTime"];
  ann.subtitle = @"%@", [stream valueForKey:@"Type"]; 
  ann.coordinate = getCoordinates;

  [mapView addAnnotation:ann];

  }
}
```

Here is the code for DisplayMap

DisplayMap.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>


@interface DisplayMap : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
    NSString *title; 
    NSString *subtitle;
    }

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 


@end
```

And now DisplayMap.m

```
#import "DisplayMap.h"

@implementation DisplayMap

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;


-(void)dealloc{
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
    }

@end
```

Comment: Is it a problem that copy is set as readOnly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is getCoordinates?  Whatever the case, its definitely not being initialized right.

Assuming that your storing Latitude and Longitude as strings in your dictionary, this should do the trick.

```
double lat = [[stream valueForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
double lon = [[stream valueForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = { lat, lon };

DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
ann.title = [stream valueForKey:@"TheTime"];
ann.subtitle = [stream valueForKey:@"Type"]; 
ann.coordinate = coord;

[mapView addAnnotation:ann];
```

Comment: Hi matheeeny -- thanks for your help! This is definitely a step in the right direction... although, I think I'm still doing something wrong. I now get the following error "-[DisplayMap setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x822e520" and "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DisplayMap setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x822e520'"

Comment: This shouldn't even compile since DisplayMap.coordinate is readonly.  Try removing the readonly attribute.

Comment: Amazing! It worked for the iPhone 4 simulator... but crashes on iPhone 3.x

Comment: Nevermind... CLLocationCoordinate2D only works for iOS 4.x ... thanks for all of the help matheeeny! Really appreciate it.

Comment: CLLocationCoordiante2D has been around since 2.0, whats not available is the make function, CLLocationCoordinate2D.  I updated the code in the answer to provide a more general CLLocationCoordinate2D init

Answer (score 0):

At first glance :

```
  ann.title = @"%@", [stream valueForKey:@"TheTime"];
```

should be

```
  ann.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [stream valueForKey:@"TheTime"]];
```

I guess

Comment: Thanks Deniz. That helped with my title and subtitle, but that does not work with the "ann.coordinate". I get the following error: "Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setCoordinate'"